# Variables in Bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I am attempting to create a script that shows how much memory every user on the system is using in their home directory. Everything was going smooth till I started using the `du -sh` command to start pulling information about specific users. I attempt to run:

```
du -sh ~currentUser
enter code here
```

I understand how the command works in command line. How do I get it to work while using a variable username? Below `reguser` is dummy account I have on my system I use to screw around with.

```
:/home/reguser/Documents# du -sh ~reguser
```

Gives output of

`71M    /home/reguser`

Comment: I was able to use du "/home/$currentUser". But why can't i use the ~ to reference the home Dir in the command?

Comment: Don't add comments to your own question, use the EDIT button to add information and improve your question.

Comment: Since when does `~` expands to `/home/`? It's supposed to expand to the current value of the `HOME` env var.

Comment: @TomYan `~` alone expands to `$HOME` but `~username` expands to homedir of that user from `getpwnam` (equivalent to `getent passwd`, as in glenn's answer) and nowadays distros usually default user homedirs to `/home/$user`

Answer (score 2):

It's because, in the order of [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions), tilde expansion occurs *before* variable expansion.

Instead of assuming "/home" you can use

```sh
getent passwd $user | cut -d: -f6
```